# Detailed step of Dijkstra's algorithm performance analysis

Tags: algorithm-analysis, search-algorithms

Reading the book of [Dasgupta-Papadimitriou-Vazirani.pdf](http://algorithmics.lsi.upc.edu/docs/Dasgupta-Papadimitriou-Vazirani.pdf)  about the performance of Dijkstra's algorithm on Page 118, we are given:

> #### 4.4.3 Running time
>
> At the level of abstraction of Figure 4.8, Dijkstra's algorithm is structurally identical to breadth-first search. However, it is slower because the priority queue primitives are computationally more demanding than the constant-time `eject`'s and `inject`'s of BFS. Since `makequeue`takes at most as long as $|V|$ `insert` operations, we get a total of $|V|$ `deletemin` and $|V| + |E|$ `insert`/`decreasekey` operations. The time needed for these varies by implementation; for instance, a binary heap gives an overall running time of $O((|V|+|E|)\log |V|)$.

I understand that it has $|V|$ `insert` and `deletemin` operations but can someone please explain why we have $|V|+|E|$ `insert`/`decreasekey` operations? First of of all, why does one algorithm have TWO kinds of insert operations? If they are the same kind, then where can we learn more about what `decreasekey` actually does?  The Wikipedia page doesn't seem to cover it much either (unless I missed or misunderstood it).

Comment: Note: Dijkstra, not Dijstake. If it helps, it's pronounced "DEEK-struh" or, more often in English-speaking countries (but less authentically), "DIKE-struh".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since makequeue takes at most as long as $|V|$ `insert` operations, we get a total of $|V|$ `deletemin` and $|V | + |E|$ `insert/decreasekey` operations.
>   First of of all, why one algorithm has TWO kinds of insert operations, if they are the same kind, then where can we learn more about what `decreasekey` actually does?

No, there is only one kind of `insert` operation. We got

- $|V|$ `deletemin` operations.
- a total of at most $|V|+|E|$ operations, where each operation is either an `insert` operation or a `decreasekey` operation. We count these two kinds of operations together because it takes the same asymptotic time to do either one of them, $O(\log |V|)$.  More specifically. we have

  - |V| `insert` operations during `makequeue`.
  - at most |E| `decreasekey` operations as each edge may or may not lead to a `decreasekey` operation.

Comment: Ok, we only have one kind of insert operation, which as the book pointed out, |V| insert. Then you explain that "we got a total of |V|+|E| operations, where each operation is either insert operation or decreasekey besides |V| deletemin"  Is the |V| insert operations included in the |V|+|E| operations?  Seem like (|V|+|E| ) include the insert operation and decreasekey operations,  and |E| is counted as all vertices performed decreasekey operations on its edges as @desiredeveloper pointed out ?

Comment: Yes, $|E|$ is counted as each edge may (or may not) lead to a `decreasekey` operation. Please check my updated answer. Is it clear now (Please forget desiredeveloper's answer for the moment, since it is not easy to follow his answer as he made several suspicious or incorrect arguments.)

Comment: Now, you are making it more interesting. Can you please give an example when an edge is led to decreasekey, and an example is not.?

Comment: For example, in Figure 4.9, each of the edges $AB, AC,CB,CD,CE,BD, BE$ leads to `decreasekey` while none of the rest of edges, $BC, ED$ does.

Comment: yes. I did actually run through code, but first time learning it just didn't recall when you point out( as I didn't catch that detail) , but now re-visiting it makes more sense, Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

In worst case the number of delete operations are bounded by O(V) and now for each delete operation you perform on each vertex you may have to perform in worst case O(V-1) decrease-key operation as it may be adjacent to V-1 vertex considering a complete graph. Now total number of decrease key operations are bounded by O(E).

vertex 1 ---> v-1 decrease key (1 vertex removed from heap,added to visited)

vertex 2 ---> v-2 decrease key (2 vertex removed from heap,added to visited)

vertex 3 ---> v-3 decrease key

vertex 4 ---> v-4 decrease key

.

.

.

vertex |V| ---> 1 decrease key

total decrease key operations = $1+2+.....+(V-1) = O(V^2) = O(E)$

Comment: I am afraid that $O(V^2)\not=O(E)$. There are a couple of other suspicious or incorrect arguments.

Comment: can you please provide an instance when the equality doesn't hold? For connected graph we can have maximum of $O(V^2)$ edges hence is bounded.

Comment: It should be the other way around, $O(|E|)=O(|V|^2)$. Suppose the graph is a tree. Then $|E|=|V|-1$.

Comment: @desiredeveloper, so as you pointed out, The |E| of ( |V|+|E| ) insert/decreasekey comes from the sum of each vertex's edges?   In other word, we iterate each vertex's edge to preform  decreasekey?